# Can every solvable problem be solved using any algorithm design?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

I recently started reading theory behind algorithms.
I then started thinking about "what if we abstract problems and algorithms, so you would be able to implement a generic system that can solve most problems.".
Unfortunately I was not able to find information on this topic. Logic Programming comes pretty close I guess, but I don't think it would be easy to make a library with something like that.

As the question suggests, this 'generic algorithm' would only solve 'generic problems' and the problems will obviously have to be (proven) solvable in the first place. I thought every problem that is solvable through what Wikipedia categorizes as 'algorithms by design' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm#By_design_paradigm) make good candidates.

So the actual question becomes more something like:"Can we define an abstract problem that is solvable by an abstract algorithm, that employs Backtracking, Divide & Conquer etc.?".

I think something like this is possible, that such an abstract representation of a problems exist that it can be solved by any of these algorithms.

Comment: Might as well make it able to reproduce itself also. Oh, that's right: humans.

Comment: A generic algorithm will not be optimal. See the informal [no free lunch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem): “if an algorithm performs well on a certain class of problems then it necessarily pays for that with degraded performance on the set of all remaining problems.” Note that we do use general problem solving machines – computers. Now the difficulty is phrasing our actual problems so that the computer is able to understand it. See also the [Curry–Howard equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence): Programs *are* proofs.

Comment: The question may have been already answered in [Theoretical Computer Science site](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), though it may be the case that nobody except those in the academia can fully understand and explain the answer.

Comment: Even the Wikipedia article you linked to mentions the unsolvability of the "Entscheidungsproblem". So -1 for not doing your research well.

Comment: @amon That is a helpful analogy.

Comment: @Doc Brown I read about that problem some while ago already. I had no I idea it was about this subject. I also know the related Halting Problem, but that's why I thought a subgroup of problems might have a generic algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because of [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion). Read also (as commented by [CandledOrange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/131624/candiedorange)) about [P vs NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)

Some problems (e.g. the [travelling saleman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)) are in theory solvable, but in practice [intractable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Intractability).

A lot of practical questions fall in this category (e.g. [optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler), [cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography))

And some problems are unsolvable (e.g. can be reduced to the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)), notably most questions of [static source code analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) (if you want reliable and sound answers), e.g. static detection of [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). See also [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

Intractable or unsolvable problems (or ill-defined ones) are actually quite common, and that is why programming is fun.

<sup>(in practice, when beginning thinking about a program, ask yourself: is the problem equivalent to the Halting Problem? Is the problem intractable?)</sup>

Read also about [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) and [Hibert's problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_problems).

Read absolutely [Gödel, Escher, Bach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach) by D.Hofstadter. It is a very good book, fun to read.

Look also into [AGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence). Read J.Pitrat's [blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/).

Comment: I think [P vs NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) fit's in here somewhere as well.

Comment: I read some of the links. I think I understand it now. Thanks!

Comment: Take a few days to read Hofstadter's *GEB*. It is very exciting!